# how can we me character array accept only alphabets in c++

Tags: c++, validation

I want to input only alphabets in character array in c++. If all the characters inputted are alphabets it must return true otherwise it returns false if there is any character other than alphabet. e.g.
Valid Input:  "AbcdefGH"   upto 20 character    Invalid Input: "AbcD12hyK"
I tried the following way but not getting desired output. Kindly help.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isValidName(char myInput[]);
int main(){
    char name[20];  
    cout<<"Enter  Name: ";
    cin.getline(name,20);
    bool input = isValidName(name);
    cout<<"Name : "<<input<<endl;   
}
bool isValidName(char myInput[])
{
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        if(!isalpha(myInput[i])){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: To begin with you risk going outside the string stored in `myInput`. That will make you check the *indeterminate* values of the array and that leads to *undefined behavior*. Unless you're required (by the exercise or assignment) to use `char` arrays, use `std::string`, otherwise remember that `char` strings in C++ are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*, and stop iterating when you reach the null-terminator `'\0'`.

Comment: Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then edit your question to include the expected as well as the actual output of your input.

Comment: Input such as `A1` *is* invalid and *should* cause `isValidName` to return `false` because of the the `1` in the input. The big problems comes when there's *no* invalid input, all the input is valid (such as the first example `AbcdefGH`)... Try to *debug* your program, either using [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), or use an actual debugger to step through the code statement by statement (stepping into the `isValidName` function) while monitoring variables and their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Some programmer dude says, it's much better to use std::string. 
The problem here is that your for loop in `isValidName()` is always checking 20 characters, but there won't always be 20 characters passed in `myInput`.

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) for cin::getline:

> A null character ('\0') is automatically appended to the written sequence if n is greater than zero, even if an empty string is extracted.

This means that your char array of 20 length could look like:

['a','b','c','\0', undefined...]

As your function checks ALL 20 characters, you'll be checking the undefined characters, which may not be an alphabet character. Hence your function doesn't provide the correct output. I slightly changed your code and got the desired output.

```
bool isValidName(char myInput[])
{
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        if (myInput[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        if(!isalpha(myInput[i])){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also note that your char array can only contain 19 useful characters in your input, since you also need a final terminating null character. Using std::string will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I'm (partially) wrong in my comments. The [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) function will return zero on the terminating null, which means that the `isValidName` will *always* return `false` (for terminated strings).

You *will* however go out of bounds if you pass an unterminated string to the function. This will not happen as long as you're only using [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) to read input though.

To solve both problems (always returning false and not risking going out of bounds) you should check both bounds *and* for the terminator in the loop condition:

```
for(int i=0; i<20 && myInput[i]!='\0; i++)
```

---

A better solution than doing the checking yourself explicitly like you do now is to use the [algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) function available in the standard library. Most notably [`std::any_of`, `std::all_of` or `std::none_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) (with a suitable predicate. As in

```
bool isValidName(char* myInput)
{
    return std::all_of(myInput, myInput + strlen(myInput), std::isalpha);
}
```

<sub>[Note the argument type is a pointer, which is what `char myInput[]` would be treated as anyway]</sub>

The above function still have the problem if the string happens to be unterminated, but that could be solved by using `std::string` instead:

```
bool isValidName(std::string const& myInput)
{
    return std::all_of(begin(myInput), end(myInput), std::isalpha);
}
```